# Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController' in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following init method which worked perfect before Swift 1.2.

```
init(items: NSArray, views: NSArray, showPageControl: Bool, navBarBackground: UIColor){
  super.init()
```

In Swift 1.2 the line with [super.init()](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingViewSwift/blob/master/SLPagingViewSwift/SLPagingViewSwift.swift#L77) raises the error:

```
Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'
```

The problem is that I have only two possible super init methods to call the one is with a `codec` and the other is with a `nib`. Both of which I do not have access to in this init method.

See the full class [here](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingViewSwift/blob/master/SLPagingViewSwift/SLPagingViewSwift.swift) the line of the error is [this](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingViewSwift/blob/master/SLPagingViewSwift/SLPagingViewSwift.swift#L77).

**How can I correct the init method to make it work with Swift 1.2?**

```
class SLPagingViewSwift: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

  init(items: NSArray, views: NSArray, showPageControl: Bool, navBarBackground: UIColor){
        super.init()
        needToShowPageControl             = showPageControl
        navigationBarView.backgroundColor = navBarBackground
        isUserInteraction                 = true
        var i: Int                        = 0
        for item in items{
            if item.isKindOfClass(UIView.classForCoder()){
                var v             = item as UIView
                var vSize: CGSize = v.isKindOfClass(UILabel.classForCoder()) ? self.getLabelSize(v as UILabel) : v.frame.size
                var originX       = (self.SCREENSIZE.width/2.0 - vSize.width/2.0) + CGFloat(i * 100)
                v.frame           = CGRectMake(originX, 8, vSize.width, vSize.height)
                v.tag             = i
                var tap           = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapOnHeader:")
                v.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
                v.userInteractionEnabled = true
                self.navigationBarView.addSubview(v)
                self.navItems.addObject(v)
                i++
            }
        }

        if (views.count > 0){
            var controllerKeys = NSMutableArray()
            i = 0
            for controller in views{
                if controller.isKindOfClass(UIView.classForCoder()){
                    var ctr = controller as UIView
                    ctr.tag = i
                    controllerKeys.addObject(NSNumber(integer: i))
                }
                else if controller.isKindOfClass(UIViewController.classForCoder()){
                    var ctr      = controller as UIViewController
                    ctr.view.tag = i
                    controllerKeys.addObject(NSNumber(integer: i))
                }
                i++
            }

            if controllerKeys.count == views.count {
               self.viewControllers = NSDictionary(objects: views, forKeys: controllerKeys)
            }
            else{
                var exc = NSException(name: "View Controllers error", reason: "Some objects in viewControllers are not kind of UIViewController!", userInfo: nil)
                exc.raise()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[Full Code](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingViewSwift/blob/master/SLPagingViewSwift/SLPagingViewSwift.swift)

Comment: Is this for SLPagingViewSwift?  I updated the super.init() to super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing a view controller class for other people to use as part of their own app. If this view controller could have a nib file, then what you are doing would be wrong and would always have been wrong: it would be up to you to allow the caller to supply the nib file name *as one of the parameters* of your initializer, so that you could call `init(nibName:bundle:)` and pass that value along.

But I gather that your view controller just uses the default empty automatic view, so this is not a problem in actual fact.

Therefore what you'll do is call `init(nibName:bundle:)`, and since this view controller has no nib file, just pass `nil` for the nib name. This in fact is what `super.init()` was doing in the earlier version of Swift - it was calling `init(nibName:bundle:)` with `nil` values for you. So nothing is really lost or changed.

Comment: It might help you to read my book's explanation of how a view controller gets its view: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_controller_and_view_creation